# Displaying the parameters/values in the string?

Tags: php

I have created a little function that does what I expected, but I am wondering is there away to display the values given the the function (10,73) rather than having to type the numbers into the string literally? Then I could display the  values given, so when you where reading the output you wouldn't have to try and work out the questions to the answers.

How do I display 10,73 in the string without typing it out ?

```
<?php

   function math($one, $two){

   $multiply = $one * $two;
   $divide = $one / $two;
   $subtract = $one - $two;

   return array($multiply,$divide,$subtract);

};


list($multiply_result, $divide_result, $sub_result) = math(10,73);

// This is what I would really like to display without having to put the 10,73 in.
// $results =  " 10 * 73 is " . $multiply_result . "<br/>";
// $results .= " 10 / 73 is " . $divide_result . "<br/>";
// $results .= " 10 - 73 is  " . $sub_result . "<<br/>>";


// This is the current way that I am displaying my values.
$results =  $multiply_result . " " . $divide_result .  "  " . $sub_result . "<p>";

echo $results;

?>
```

Comment: could you explain it a little bit more? i did not get your question

Comment: How do I display 10,73 in the string without typing it out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set fourth and fifth element to your array;

```
function math($one, $two){

   $multiply = $one * $two;
   $divide = $one / $two;
   $subtract = $one - $two;

   return array($multiply,$divide,$subtract, $one, $two);

};
```

And use it like

```
list($multiply_result, $divide_result, $sub_result, $one, $two) = math(10,73);  

$results =  " $one * $two is $multiply_result <br/>";
$results .= " $one / $two is $divide_result <br/>";
$results .= " $one - $two is $sub_result <br/>";

echo $results;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the values to a variable and use the variable inside the string like below.

```
<?php

   function math($one, $two){

   $multiply = $one * $two;
   $divide = $one / $two;
   $subtract = $one - $two;

   return array($multiply,$divide,$subtract);

};


$param1 = 10;
$param2 = 73;
list($multiply_result, $divide_result, $sub_result) = math($param1,$param2);


$results =  " $param1 * $param2 is " . $multiply_result . "<br/>";
$results .= " $param1 / $param2 is " . $divide_result . "<br/>";
$results .= " $param1 - $param2 is  " . $sub_result . "<br/>";

echo $results;

?>
```

Comment: That was copied from the question